# How to replace the array portion of an index function to have it choose whatever column matches the header?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I am trying to replace the array portion of an index to match against whatever is in a specific cell to whatever column has that.

[image: Example of what the data looks like]

Like in the picture, I can manually tell the index/match to check column G for the numbers to pull.
The actual data is a few hundred columns in no particular order so I want to replace that array selection portion to instead look at the parent letter (A or B or C) and then pick the column where that is the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the third criterion:

```
=INDEX($G$4:$I$6,MATCH($B7,$F$4:$F$6,0),MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:$A7<>""),$A$1:$A7),$G$3:$I$3,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! I'm not certain what to do regarding this portion of the code LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:$A4<>""),$A$1:$A4)

How am I specifying the parent variable to find the column with?

Comment: @squeeep `LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:$A7<>""),$A$1:$A7)` returns the last cell with a value in column A, above or equal to A7.  As it is dragged down it adds one more row to the range.

Comment: Ooops, dum dum alert on my part. Thank you for explaining. If I'm honest I'm still a little confused about how you wrote the code. Mainly due to the final product being using the index/match on the same cells of different sheets. I believe you've provided enough of a starting point for me to figure it out myself (gotta learn it) Thank you again my guy, you're awesome!

Comment: If this works for you please considering marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.